# How can I upload and replace a Wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I just created my first Wordpress theme. I zipped it up and installed it on the server using the Wordpress 3.0.1 [Administration Panel](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Themes#Adding_New_Themes_using_the_Administration_Panel). That worked fine. But now I've made a few changes to my theme and I want to update it. I couldn't find an "upgrade" option for uploaded themes so I tried just uploading it again. This is what I got.

> *Installing Theme from uploaded file:
>   my-theme.zip*
>
> Unpacking the package…
>
> Installing the theme…
>
> Destination folder already exists.
>   /path/to/wordpress/wp-content/themes/my-theme/
>
> Theme install failed.

Is there any way to update the theme through the administration panel? Or do I have to access the filesystem somehow (FTP, etc.) and delete the directory first?

Comment: I have the issue, were you able to find a way to automatically delete the theme ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it all through the control panel.   Each theme has a [Delete link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Themes_SubPanel) that you can use to wipe it from the server's file system.   Once it's gone, you can re-intall your updated version.